# Why hash(#) not remove from a string using str_replace in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I have tried below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var hasvalue = window.location.hash;
</script>
<?php
$ValHas = "<script>document.writeln(hasvalue);</script>";
echo $ValHas."<br>"; // Display #123-12555 
echo str_replace("#","",$ValHas); // Display again #123-12555 
?>
```

What I am missing there?

Comment: if you want to remove # the use this `var hasvalue = window.location.hash.replace('#','');`

Comment: Working https://3v4l.org/Z9vka

Comment: @B.Desai basically it is working using like $ValHas = "#123-12555"; I know very well but when I use above code it still display # in staring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$ValHas` is still a *string* in PHP, with a value of `"<script>document.writeln(hasvalue);</script>"`. It has no `#`s. It doesn't get turned into `'#123-12555 '` until the client's Javascript evaluates the function.

If you want to remove the hash client-side, do this:

`var hasvalue = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');`

Comment: Yes It working thanks. What is the main reason to not remove hash in php? using str_replace.

Comment: Because in PHP, there's no hash in the string - the string that the PHP sees does not have a `#` there.

Comment: ok Thank you very much @CertainPerformance about It. It will help me in future.